# Difference between app-debug.apk and app-debug-unaligned.apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

In android studio with build variant set to "debug" mode, I found two outputs of apk

- app-debug.apk
- app-debug-unaligned.apk

What is the differences between those files?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The unaligned apk is just an intermediate apk. First, the unaligned apk is generated. Then, the unaligned apk gets aligned and produces the aligned apk which is the app-debug.apk. You can read more about it over [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Answer (score 76):

### Short Answer:

`app-debug-unaligned.apk` = Unaligned Signed APK 
`app-debug.apk` = Aligned Signed APK (RAM optimized using zipalign)

---

### Long Answer

To understand the difference we need to know the following points:

#### App signing process

- generate a private key ***(keytool)***
- compile to get the unsigned APK -> unaligned unsigned APK
- Sign app in debug/release mode using private key ***(jarsigner)*** -> unaligned signed APK
- align the APK ***(zipalign)*** -> aligned signed APK

The entire signing process is explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually).

#### Why do we need the intermediate `app-debug-unaligned.apk` at all?

as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html):

> **Caution:** zipalign must only be performed **after** the .apk file has been
>   signed with your private key. If you perform zipalign before signing,
>   then the signing procedure will undo the alignment.

#### What is the advantage? zipalign?

The advantage is that aligned APKs are optimized for RAM usage so they will consume less RAM in the devices. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html):

> zipalign is an archive alignment tool that provides important
>   optimization to Android application (.apk) files. ....The benefit is a
>   reduction in the amount of RAM consumed when running the application.