# Have trouble with app-debug.apk when app-debug-unaligned.apk is not

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, nfc, zipalign

I am developing an NFC-integrated Android Application using Android Studio.

I have 2 activities: one is about NFC Tag Reader and other is NFC Tag Writer.
Everything works  fine (Reader/Writer) when I the run app in my phone.

After that, I went to `workspace\app\build\outputs\apk` and see 2 apks here `app-debug.apk | app-debug-unaligned.apk`.

I saw a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366905/difference-between-app-debug-apk-and-app-debug-unaligned-apk) that said `app-debug` is a complete app. But when I install `app-debug.apk` then NFC Tag Writer does not work.

I removed and installed `app-debug-unaligned.apk`, this apk worked perfectly.

I tried to find on Google but nothing found. Anyone has an idea about this? Please tell me which part of my code for should be shown here to review.

**P.S.**: I tried adding keystroke but NFC Tag Writer still not work.

Comment: http://www.monkey-x.com/Community/posts.php?topic=695