# how to generate app-androidTest-unaligned.apk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, unsigned, signed

This afternoon i update my sdk,then i ran my app just as usual,i got an error like this.

**`${dir}\[appname]-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk` does not exist on disk**

i try to build and clean the project,but no use.I use android-studio.

Comment: Dont create title as link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The APK file does not exist on disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Comment: This is actually missing using android gradle plugin 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project folder. Open ProjectName folder.

In file **Your_Project_name.iml**

Add if not **OR** check path

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/your_app_name-debug-unaligned.apk" />
```

Or

```
<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/outputs/apk/your_app_name-debug-unaligned.apk"/>
```

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366905/difference-between-app-debug-apk-and-app-debug-unaligned-apk) for more information.

Comment: Hello,It don't work to me,i find there is no apk file in "/buid/outputs".but when i buid apk ,the tool inform this: "Build APK
         APK(s) generated successfully." but i cant find any apk file.Thanks for your answer

Comment: this will set path of your apk generated

Comment: try setting different path and check if you find apk there or not.

Answer (score 6):

Run `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest` gradle task and it should be created in outputs directory, but it gets ereased on every project clean

Comment: can you specify the app module to build?

Comment: Sure you can:  `./gradlew moduleName:assembleAndroidTest`

Comment: `./gradlew assembleFlavorNameAndroidTest` will build apk's for only selected flavors.