# Need to save the app-unaligned-debug.apk

Tags: android, apk

I have a question similar to [why unaligned apk is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058210/why-unaligned-apk-is-needed) as to why the app-unaligned-apk is required.

I do understand the two step process in generating the apk but I still haven't been able to understand why the unaligned apk is stored in the outputs folder even once the required apk has been generated. Any thoughts?

Comment: The unaligned apk is just an intermediate apk. First, the unaligned apk is generated. Then, the unaligned apk gets aligned and produces the aligned apk which is the app-debug.apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why unaligned apk is needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058210/why-unaligned-apk-is-needed)

Comment: No, that is not my question. My question is why do we need to save the intermediate apk once the apk is generated. Any uses of the intermediate apk?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33886306/3193867

Answer (score 0):

@Courtesy goes to **[Difference between app-debug.apk and app-debug-unaligned.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366905/difference-between-app-debug-apk-and-app-debug-unaligned-apk)**

> The unaligned apk is just an intermediate apk. First, the unaligned
>   apk is generated. Then, the unaligned apk gets aligned and produces
>   the aligned apk which is the app-debug.apk.

Read [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

The build process of Android projects is handled by the Gradle build system. If you create a new project in Android studio, the Gradle build scripts are automatically created. Android studio wraps the Gradle runtime, hence no additional installation is required.

- Multi-apk: supporting the creation of multiple apk for different
  device types while reusing parts of the code

> Android Studio, make it easy to create several variants of an
>   application, either for multi-apk distribution or for different
>   flavors of an application. This means, you can have different builds
>   for debug, release or may be different variant build from the same
>   code.